# Get the nth word or the last word if apporopriate

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a great little piece of code to pull names out of one cell and separate them into separate cells. The number of names varies greatly and as such I need to automate it as much as possible.

I am using the following macro:

```
Function Get_Word(text_string As String, nth_word) As String
    Dim lWordCount As Long

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        lWordCount = Len(text_string) - Len(.Substitute(text_string, " ", "")) + 1

        If IsNumeric(nth_word) Then
            nth_word = nth_word - 1
            Get_Word = Mid(Mid(Mid(.Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", nth_word), 1, 256), _
                .Find("^", .Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", nth_word)), 256), 2, _
                .Find(" ", Mid(Mid(.Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", nth_word), 1, 256), _
                .Find("^", .Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", nth_word)), 256)) - 2)

        ElseIf nth_word = "First" Then
            Get_Word = Left(text_string, .Find(" ", text_string) - 1)

        ElseIf nth_word = "Last" Then
            Get_Word = Mid(.Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", Len(text_string) - _
                Len(.Substitute(text_string, " ", ""))), .Find("^", .Substitute(text_string, " ", "^", _
                Len(text_string) - Len(.Substitute(text_string, " ", "")))) + 1, 256)

        End If
    End With

End Function
```

I can then specify which word goes into which column (e.g. `get_word(j2, 4)`).

Unfortunately I have hit a snag, if a specific word is the last word in its cell it will not be extracted unless I specify ( e.g. `get_word(j2, "Last")`). This is making it tricky to do and will mean I will have to go through cells individually.

What I would really love to know if there is any way to change the VBA script above so that in Excel I can specify that I want the 4th word or the "last" word if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Function Get_Word(text_string As String, nth_word) As String
    Dim vWords
    Dim lWordCount As Long

    vWords = Split(text_string, " ")

    lWordCount = UBound(vWords) + 1

    If IsNumeric(nth_word) Then
        If nth_word < 1 Then nth_word = 1
        If nth_word > lWordCount Then nth_word = lWordCount
        Get_Word = vWords(nth_word - 1)
    ElseIf nth_word = "First" Then

        Get_Word = vWords(0)

    ElseIf nth_word = "Last" Then

        Get_Word = vWords(lWordCount - 1)
    End If

End Function
```

If you want nothing back if you pass too large a value:

```
Function Get_Word(text_string As String, nth_word) As String
    Dim vWords
    Dim lWordCount As Long

    vWords = Split(text_string, " ")

    lWordCount = UBound(vWords) + 1

    If IsNumeric(nth_word) Then
        If nth_word > lWordCount Then
          Get_Word = ""
        Else
         If nth_word < 1 Then nth_word = 1

         Get_Word = vWords(nth_word - 1)
        End If
    ElseIf nth_word = "First" Then

        Get_Word = vWords(0)

    ElseIf nth_word = "Last" Then

        Get_Word = vWords(lWordCount - 1)
    End If

End Function
```

You can still use =Get_Word(A1,"Last") if you want, but if you use =Get_Word(A1,3) and there are only 2 words, you'll get an empty string back.

Comment: +1 though `ElseIf nth_word = "First"` is rather redundant! (I'm thinking `nth_word = 1`.)

Comment: I figure as the original had that option, it might already be in use in formulas, so...

Comment: Just want to ask one more question regarding this guys. The code is working great, just one quick question, if I take out:

    ElseIf nth_word = "Last" Then

        Get_Word = vWords(lWordCount - 1)

Will that mean that it will only pull the specified number, and leave the last?

Comment: It means you will have to use a specific word number - you won't be able to just ask for the last word wherever that happens to be.

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry for being a pain. I ahve removed the ElseIf nth_word = "Last" and it still is returning the last entry. Do you of anything else that might work. Again thanks for all your help.

Comment: If the number you pass is greater than or equal to the word count, you will still get the last word. The "Last" option allowed you to just pass "Last" to the function rather than a specific number. I'm not clear on what you want changed?

Comment: I see, what I wanted was that if I passed the word count (requested get_word(j2, 5) and there were only words in the cell, I wanted nothing returned. But thats ok, if there is no other option I can live with it :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative version.